# How to decode a unicode character in string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, decode

I have the following String:

```
Conversely, companies that aren\u0019t sharp-eyed enough to see that their real Dumbwaiter Pitches are lame, tired, or just plain evil \u0014 well, they usually end up facing extinction.
```

This string contains '\u0019t'. I cannot decode, because it's already a string. If I encode first, then decode, it still shows '\u0019t'. How do I get this to show a ' ?

Comment: Unicode 19 is not a printable character, so there was a mistake made during encoding I presume. Whatever you try, it is unlikely that it will result in a apostrophe. Unless you find / decode it yourself by explicitely creating a map from value `0019` hex to the apostrophe.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to literal_eval it:

```
import ast
s = r"Conversely, companies that aren\u0019t sharp-eyed enough to see that their real Dumbwaiter Pitches are lame, tired, or just plain evil \u0014 well, they usually end up facing extinction. \u2661"
r = ast.literal_eval(f'"{s}"')
print(r)
```

Output:

```
Conversely, companies that arent sharp-eyed enoughto see that their real Dumbwaiter Pitches are lame, tired, or just plain evil  well, they usually endup facing extinction. ♡
```

Comment: This [doesn't seem to work](https://repl.it/repls/HarmoniousAdvancedLegacysystem)

Comment: @bereal Missed some quotes. Try now

Comment: Of course, Unicode 19 is not a printable character, so it is still missing in action.

Comment: Yeah. I added a heart to the end for that reason... @FelipeFaria The unicode characters in the OPs string aren't printable.

Comment: Well, that won't make it anymore printable. That's more of a problem of the question of course, but yeah.

Comment: Yup -- @Maarten-reinstateMonica clarified right before I pressed "Add Comment." Checked it again and it is working. Good solution.

Comment: @bereal did turning into a raw string change anything? I don't mind but it seems the effect is the same. Since the OP doesn't have it as a raw string I am going to keep it as a regular string to match the OPs predicament.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse without `r` the code example does not really prove the solution, because all the codes are substituted already before calling `literal_eval` :)

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, the Unicode escape string is 2000 hex off the mark. Unicode dash and apostrophe are:

[Unicode Character 'EM DASH' (U+2014)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2014/index.htm)

and

[Unicode Character 'RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK' (U+2019)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm)

So lets fix it anyway, even if the error is at the source (THEM) not the destination:

```py
import re
text = r'Conversely, companies that aren\u0019t sharp-eyed enough to see that their real Dumbwaiter Pitches are lame, tired, or just plain evil \u0014 well, they usually end up facing extinction.'
pattern = r'\\u([0-9a-fA-F]{4})'

# used to indicate the end of the previous match
# to save the string parts that don't need character encoding
off = 0
# start with an empty string
s = r''
# find and iterate over all matches of \uHHHH where H is a hex digit
for u in re.finditer(pattern, text):
    # append anything up to the unicode escape
    s += text[off:u.start()]
    # fix encoding mistake, unicode escapes are 2000 hex off the mark
    # then append it
    s += chr(int(u.group(1), 16) + 0x2000)
    # set off to the end of the match
    off = u.end()
# append everything from the last match to the end of the line
s += text[off:len(text)]
print(s)
```

prints out

```
Conversely, companies that aren’t sharp-eyed enough to see that their real Dumbwaiter Pitches are lame, tired, or just plain evil — well, they usually end up facing extinction.
```

Note though that I've happily ignored any possible presence of `\\u00xx` in the text (where the backslash itself is escaped), that's something I'll leave for you to solve. Any *correct* Unicode escapes in the text will, of course, be altered as well.

Comment: "Conversely, companies that aren't sharp-eyed enough to see that their *character encoding routines* are lame, tired, or just plain evil - well, they usually end up facing extinction."